# java how to declare a stream is not empty?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a non-empty collection(I can guarantee), and I'm gonna do lots of reduce operation on that. However when you do a reduce operation in a stream, it return an `Optional`, which is annoying. I can use `orElse` to provide a default value but this make my code very confusing(that default value will never be used)

Basically, I know the stream is non-empty, how should I declare this to Java so it won't output an `Optional` which will never be null. Is there any elegant way to do this?

```
Collection c = fromSomeWhere...;
if (c.empty()) {
  throw Exception();
}

c.reduce()....;
c.reduce().....;
c.reduce().....;
```

Comment: If you think `Optional` will not be empty, then why not use `get` always ?

Comment: "However when you do a reduce operation in a stream, it return an Optional, which is annoying." - If you are annoyed by the `Optional` you don't have to use the method that returns it. 
 For example, there is a `reduce` method that accepts an identity value as the first parameter. 
 That method does not return an `Optional`. 
 See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: How about achieving the desired behavior without using Java stream? Which I believe is possible in this case.

Comment: "How about achieving the desired behavior without using Java stream?" - If you are asking if the reduction could be done without a stream, the answer is yes.  There are reasons not to do that, but it could certainly be done.

Comment: Since Java 10, you can use `orElseThrow()` instead of `get()`, to the same result but being more explicit about the assumption that this optional is not empty. In all versions, you could use `orElseThrow(() -> new AssertionError("stream should not be empty"))`

Comment: I think [Jeff Scott Brown's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089715/java-how-to-declare-a-stream-is-not-empty#comment120345069_68089715) answer should be the accepted one.